# When trying to create a new Django CreateView form, my forms are being populated with the data that was entered in the last form

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

Using Class Based Views, ModelForms, and Inlline Formsets. I’m making a recipe application in Django. Each user has their own OneToOne RecipeBook object, which in turn can hold as many recipes as needed, as each Recipe has a ForeignKey relationship to the RecipeBook object. There are also Ingredient and Direction objects that each have a FK relationship to the Recipe object.

The good news is that I can create a Recipe object using my CreateView, with as many associated Ingredient and Direction objects as I want. The Ingredient/Direction objects should be unique to each Recipe object (and by extension, each User). However, when I create a Recipe object, and then I try to create a new Recipe object, its Ingredient and Direction fields are already populated on the new object, form the old object. So if I had just created a Recipe with 3 Ingredient/Direction fields all set to '1', and then go to create another Recipe, the new Recipe object will have all blank fields, but will have 3 Ingredient/Direction objects all set to 1. This will happen to each user that is logged in. I want to make it so these objects are all staying together.

I think the issue to this is that either my get_context_data or my form_valid methods are saving the Ingredient/Direction objects globally, when I just want each Ingredient/Direction object to only be associated with the specific recipe object. I’ve tried messing with the init function of my Forms, I’ve tried querying for the object before/while its being created, and it seems like no matter what I do I’m just running in circles. I’d appreciate any help/resources anyone can point me towards!

My Models:

```
class RecipeBook(models.Model):
    """Each user has a single associated RecipeBook object, linked in this OneToOne field"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Recipe(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4())
    recipebook = models.ForeignKey(RecipeBook, related_name='recipe_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text='Title of the recipe')
    description = models.TextField(help_text='Description of the recipe', blank=True)
    # image = models.ImageField(height_field=, width_field=, help_text='Image of the recipe', blank=True)
    servings = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(help_text='The amount of servings the recipe will yield', default=0, blank=True)
    prep_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(help_text='The preparation time', default=0, blank=True)
    cook_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(help_text='The cooking time', default=0, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)

    TIME_UNITS = (
        ('m', 'Minutes'),
        ('h', 'Hours')
    )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('recipe_book:recipe-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, related_name='ingredient_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Direction(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, related_name='direction_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    step_instructions = models.TextField(help_text='Write the instructions of the step here')
```

My Forms:

```
class AddRecipeForm(ModelForm):
    recipe = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Recipe.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'servings', 'prep_time', 'cook_time', 'url']


class AddIngredientForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = ['name', 'amount']

    # def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     self.recipe = kwargs.pop('recipe')
    #     super(AddIngredientForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #
    #     if not self.instance:
    #         self.fields['name'].initial = self.recipe.default_name
    #     self.fields['amount'].widget = forms.TextInput(required=False)
    #
    # def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     self.instance.recipe = self.recipe
    #     ingredient = super(AddIngredientForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    #     return ingredient


IngredientFormset = inlineformset_factory(Recipe, Ingredient, form=AddIngredientForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)


class AddDirectionForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Direction
        fields = ['step_instructions']

    # def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     self.recipe = kwargs.pop('recipe')
    #     super(AddDirectionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #
    #     if not self.instance:
    #         self.fields['step_instructions'].initial = self.recipe.default_step_instructions
    #
    # def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     self.instance.recipe = self.recipe
    #     direction = super(AddDirectionForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    #     return direction


DirectionFormset = inlineformset_factory(Recipe, Direction, form=AddDirectionForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)
```

My View:

```
class RecipeListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = models.Recipe
    context_object_name = 'recipes'

    # Using this method ensures that the only recipes that are displayed are the ones associated with each user
    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Recipe.objects.filter(recipebook=self.request.user.recipebook)


class RecipeDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Recipe
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'servings', 'prep_time', 'cook_time', 'url']
    context_object_name = 'recipe'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Recipe.objects.filter(recipebook=self.request.user.recipebook)


# Classes used to actually create full recipe objects
class RecipeCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = models.Recipe
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'servings', 'prep_time', 'cook_time', 'url']

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Recipe.objects.filter(recipebook=self.request.user.recipebook)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(RecipeCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #user = self.request.user

        if self.request.POST:
            data['ingredients'] = IngredientFormset(self.request.POST)
                #queryset=models.Recipe.objects.filter(recipebook=self.request.user.recipebook))
            data['directions'] = DirectionFormset(self.request.POST)
                #queryset=models.Recipe.objects.filter(recipebook=self.request.user.recipebook))
        else:
            data['ingredients'] = IngredientFormset()
                #queryset=models.Recipe.objects.filter(self.kwargs['id']))
            data['directions'] = DirectionFormset()
                #queryset=models.Recipe.objects.filter(self.kwargs['id']))
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.recipebook = self.request.user.recipebook
        context = self.get_context_data()
        ingredients = context['ingredients']
        directions = context['directions']

        # self.object is the object being created
        self.object = form.save()

        if ingredients.is_valid():
            ingredients.instance = self.object
            ingredients.save()
        if directions.is_valid():
            directions.instance = self.object
            directions.save()

        return super(RecipeCreate, self).form_valid(form)


class RecipeUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = models.Recipe
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'servings', 'prep_time', 'cook_time', 'url']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(RecipeUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.request.POST:
            data['ingredients'] = IngredientFormset(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
                            #queryset=models.Recipe.objects.filter(recipebook=self.request.user.recipebook))
            data['directions'] = DirectionFormset(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
                            #queryset=models.Recipe.objects.filter(recipebook=self.request.user.recipebook))
        else:
            data['ingredients'] = IngredientFormset(instance=self.object)
                            #queryset=models.Recipe.objects.filter(recipebook=self.request.user.recipebook))
            data['directions'] = DirectionFormset(instance=self.object)
                            #queryset=models.Recipe.objects.filter(recipebook=self.request.user.recipebook))
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.recipebook = self.request.user.recipebook
        context = self.get_context_data()
        ingredients = context['ingredients']
        directions = context['directions']

        self.object = form.save()

        if ingredients.is_valid():
            ingredients.instance = self.object
            ingredients.save()
        if directions.is_valid():
            directions.instance = self.object
            directions.save()

        return super(RecipeUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

My Template:

```
{% extends 'base-recipe.html' %}

{# https://simpleit.rocks/python/django/dynamic-add-form-with-add-button-in-django-modelformset-template/ #}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Create Recipe</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
                    {# table for the Recipe object, manually rendering it for more control #}
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ form.title.label_tag }}</td>
                            <td>{{ form.title }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ form.description.label_tag }}</td>
                            <td>{{ form.description }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ form.servings.label_tag }}</td>
                            <td>{{ form.servings }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ form.prep_time.label_tag }}</td>
                            <td>{{ form.prep_time }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ form.cook_time.label_tag }}</td>
                            <td>{{ form.cook_time }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ form.url.label_tag }}</td>
                            <td>{{ form.url }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    {# table for the ingredient(s) object(s) #}
                    <table class="table">
                        {{ ingredients.management_form }}

                        {% for form in ingredients.forms %}
                            {% if forloop.first %}
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                        <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            {% endif %}

                            <tr class="{% cycle row1 row2 %} formset_row-{{ ingredients.prefix }}">
                            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                <td>
                                    {# include the hidden fields in the form #}
                                    {% if forloop.first %}
                                        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                            {{ hidden }}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                                    {{ field }}
                                </td>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </table>

                    <table class="table">
                    {{ directions.management_form }}
                        {% for form in directions.forms %}
                            {% if forloop.first %}
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                    <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            {% endif %}

                            <!--<tr class="{% cycle row1 row2 %} formset_row-{{ directions.prefix }}">-->
                            <tr class="formset_row-{{ directions.prefix }}">
                            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                <td>
                                    {# include the hidden fields #}
                                    {% if forloop.first %}
                                        {% for field in form.hidden_fields %}
                                            {{ hidden }}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                                    {{ field }}
                                </td>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </table>

                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'recipe_book:index' %}">Back to the recipe list</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% load static %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.formsets.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.formset_row-{{ ingredients.prefix }}').formset({
            addText: 'Add Another Ingredient',
            deleteText: 'Remove',
            prefix: '{{ ingredients.prefix }}',
        });
        $('.formset_row-{{ directions.prefix }}').formset({
            addText: 'Add another',
            deleteText: 'Remove',
            prefix: '{{ directions.prefix }}',
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who also has this issue, here's the fix, from the Django forum's user KenWhitesell:

> You can chase this down through the source code if you really want to
> understand what’s going on, but **the** **Reader’s Digest version is that an
> inline formset is created under the assumption that the formset is
> linked to an existing instance. If one isn’t supplied, it selects one
> from the database**.

The fix, for me, was in the `CreateView`'s `get_context_data()` method: since we don't want the `inline_formset` to be querying for *any* objects on a `CreateView`, you have to explicitly tell it not to with a `queryset` parameter on the `GET` request like this:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(RecipeCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.request.POST:
            data['ingredients'] = IngredientFormset(self.request.POST)
            data['directions'] = DirectionFormset(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['ingredients'] = IngredientFormset(queryset=models.Ingredient.objects.none())
            data['directions'] = DirectionFormset(queryset=models.Direction.objects.none())
        return data
```

Here's a link to our forum post discussing the issue: https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/my-forms-are-being-populated-with-the-data-that-was-entered-in-the-last-createview/6278/12